# How to pull multiple .Net repos inside a devcontainer volume using SSH key

Tags: git, docker, vscode-devcontainer

I am kinda new to Docker containers, so far I have used them, without making my own. Now we have the following scenario. We have one ASP.Net project with Postgres database. That project includes couple of sub-projects and libraries, which are stored in separate repos each. All our repos are in a local git server. We want to be able to develop this project in different OSes and environments, because some of our devs have Windows PCs, while other have Linux. We want everything to be unified and easy for the devs to use - assuming the developer will open VSCode and start the container and everything will work fine. And we want all the code to be inside the container volume - We want to end up with only one `.devcontainer` folder, which we keep in some git server, then the developer pulls it, opens it in VSCode and all the code and configurations are then pulled and built.  First of all, is this possible?

Second - here is what I have tried so far. As I mentioned I added a `.devcontainer` folder. Inside it I have the following files:
`devcontainer.json`

```json
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the
// README at: https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/tree/main/src/dotnet-postgres
{
    "name": "My Container",
    "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "app",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces/${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}",
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/apt-get-packages:1": {},
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/apt-packages:1": {},
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/bash-command:1": {}
    },
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime"
            ]
        }
    }

    // Features to add to the dev container. More info: https://containers.dev/features.
    // "features": {},

    // Configure tool-specific properties.
    // "customizations": {},

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    // "forwardPorts": [5000, 5001, 5432],
    // "portsAttributes": {
    //      "5001": {
    //          "protocol": "https"
    //      }
    // }

    // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
    //"postCreateCommand":
    // Uncomment to connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/dev-containers-non-root.
    // "remoteUser": "root"
}
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    
    environment:
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent

    volumes:
      - ../..:/workspaces:cached
      - ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}:/ssh-agent # Forward local machine SSH key to docker

    # Overrides default command so things don't shut down after the process ends.
    command: sleep infinity

    # Runs app on the same network as the database container, allows "forwardPorts" in devcontainer.json function.
    network_mode: service:db
    
    # Uncomment to connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/dev-containers-non-root.
    # user: root

    # Use "forwardPorts" in **devcontainer.json** to forward an app port locally. 
    # (Adding the "ports" property to this file will not forward from a Codespace.)
  db:
    image: postgres:14.3
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      
    # Add "forwardPorts": ["5432"] to **devcontainer.json** to forward PostgreSQL locally.
    # (Adding the "ports" property to this file will not forward from a Codespace.)
      
volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/dotnet:0-7.0

# [Optional] Uncomment this section to install additional OS packages.
RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends git

# Set the working directory to /workspace
WORKDIR /workspace

#For the test I am pulling only one repo but in reallity there should be many repos to be pulled.
RUN GIT_TRACE=1 git clone myuser@192.168.1.110:/home/myuser/repos/OneRepo.git

# [Optional] Uncomment this line to install global node packages.
# RUN su vscode -c "source /usr/local/share/nvm/nvm.sh && npm install -g <your-package-here>" 2>&1
```

As you can see, I want to pull the code in the Dockerfile (my assumption was that this will pull it inside the devcontainer volume). It starts to pull it but it has issues with the authentication. That is why I tried to forward the ssh-agent, but no luck. Tried to comment out the pull step and the container was started OK but when I open the Docker CLI and run `ssh-add -l` I am getting authentication error. On my host machine I am able to run that `git clone` command and pull the code with no issues. I have added the SSH key to the server so I don't need authentication.

I hope my question was clear enough, but I will provide more details if needed or I have missed something.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a unified development environment across different OSes using Docker. Your environment is an ASP.NET project with a Postgres database, subprojects and libraries in separate repos.
You need your code and configurations inside a single `.devcontainer` folder, pulled and built when a developer starts the container in VSCode.

```bash
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Host Machine                                        |
| +-------------------------------------------------+ |
| | Docker Container (devcontainer)                 | |
| | +---------------------------------------------+ | |
| | | VSCode Workspace                            | | |
| | | +-----------+  +-----------+  +-----------+ | | |
| | | | Repo 1    |  | Repo 2    |  | Repo N    | | | |
| | | +-----------+  +-----------+  +-----------+ | | |
| | +---------------------------------------------+ | |
| +-------------------------------------------------+ |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

To pull repos using SSH, the container must have access to SSH keys. Clone each repository within the Dockerfile or a script.

Your `devcontainer.json` seems correct. Make sure the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is forwarded correctly (`ENV SSH_AUTH_SOCK /ssh-agent` in your Dockerfile, which should include an SSH client).

Modify the Dockerfile to handle SSH keys and clone multiple repositories.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/dotnet:0-7.0

# Install git and SSH client
RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends git ssh-client

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /workspace

# Set the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable to the forwarded socket
ENV SSH_AUTH_SOCK /ssh-agent

# Copy the clone script into the container
COPY clone-repos.sh /workspace/clone-repos.sh

# Make the script executable
RUN chmod +x /workspace/clone-repos.sh

# Run the script to clone the repositories
RUN /workspace/clone-repos.sh

# [Optional] Install global node packages if needed
# RUN su vscode -c "source /usr/local/share/nvm/nvm.sh && npm install -g <your-package-here>" 2>&1
```

With `clone-repos.sh` (assuming you have a fixed list of repositories to clone):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# List of repositories to clone
# Format: "repo-url directory-name"
REPOS=(
    "ssh://myuser@192.168.1.110:/home/myuser/repos/OneRepo.git one-repo"
    "ssh://myuser@192.168.1.110:/home/myuser/repos/AnotherRepo.git another-repo"
    # Add more repositories here
)

# Clone each repository
for repo in "${REPOS[@]}"; do
    read -r url dir <<< "$repo"
    if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
        echo "Cloning $url into $dir..."
        git clone "$url" "$dir"
    else
        echo "Directory $dir already exists, skipping clone..."
    fi
done
```

For additional ideas, you can refer to [`h4l/dev-container-docker-compose-volume-or-bind`](https://github.com/h4l/dev-container-docker-compose-volume-or-bind), which also uses a workspace in volume or bind mount.

---

The error `pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory` indicates a problem with accessing the SSH agent socket inside the Docker container. The SSH agent forwarding is not working as intended, which is why the container cannot use the SSH keys from the host machine.

Make sure the SSH agent socket is correctly mounted in your `docker-compose.yml`. The relevant line should look something like this:

```yaml
volumes:
     - ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}:/ssh-agent
```

Check if the environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is correctly set on the host machine. Run `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` on the host to see its value.

In your Dockerfile, you are setting `ENV SSH_AUTH_SOCK /ssh-agent`. That should match the path where the SSH agent socket is mounted in the container. Verify that this matches with the volume mounting in the `docker-compose.yml`.

In your `clone-repos.sh` script, before the `git clone` command, explicitly set the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable:

```bash
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -vvv" git clone ...
```

Within the container, check if SSH is trying to use the correct agent socket. You can do this by running `ssh-add -l` or `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` inside the container.

For testing purpose, try to manually SSH into the Git server from within the container to further isolate the issue. Use `ssh -Tvvv git@<git-server>`

Consider who the user is within the container when the SSH commands are run. If the Docker container runs as a non-root user, but your setup assumes root, there might be a mismatch in accessing the SSH agent socket.

---

> Does the Personal Access Token (PAT) work with local repos? I have seen it in GitHub, but since my server is in my local server, would that work there as well?
> All I need to do is clone, push and pull. No other operations
> And what are the security implications of copying the ssh folder? I am not planning to publish the container, I will use it only for development purposes.

Personal Access Tokens (PATs) are primarily a feature of hosted Git services like GitHub, GitLab, and Bitbucket. For local Git servers, PATs are not a standard feature unless your server is running a service that implements a similar token authentication system. For standard SSH-based Git servers, PATs are not applicable.

If your local Git server is set up to use HTTP/HTTPS and supports basic authentication, you could theoretically use a username and password combination, which in some systems can be substituted with a token-like system. However, this depends entirely on how your local Git server is configured.

I mentioned copying SSH keys into a Docker container only for testing purposes. I would not recommend it, as it comes with several security implications (private key exposure, container isolation compromised, key management within container).

Given your requirements for basic Git operations (clone, push, pull) on a local server, consider creating a new SSH key pair specifically for use within your Docker containers. Restrict the permissions of this key as much as possible (e.g., read-only access to repositories, limited to specific operations). Securely mount this key into your container, and configure Git to use it.

---

The OP reports in [the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/57004841#57004841) using the Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/dotnet:0-7.0

# [Optional] Uncomment this section to install additional OS packages.
RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
&& apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends git ssh-client

# Set the working directory to /workspace
WORKDIR /workspace

COPY id_ed25519 /root/.ssh/id_ed25519

RUN GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -vvv" git clone xequtor@192.168.68.210:/home/xequtor/repos/Duhnja.git
```

And `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    environment:
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent

    volumes:
      - ../..:/workspaces:cached
      - $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent # Forward local machine SSH key to docker

    # Overrides default command so things don't shut down after the process ends.
    command: sleep infinity

    # Runs app on the same network as the database container, allows "forwardPorts" in devcontainer.json function.
    network_mode: service:db
```

The main modification that led to the successful mounting of the SSH agent socket in the Docker container is the addition of the line `COPY id_ed25519 /root/.ssh/id_ed25519` in the Dockerfile.
That change involves directly copying an SSH private key (`id_ed25519`) from the host into the container's file system.
That allows the container to use this key for SSH operations, such as cloning from your Git server.

By copying the SSH key into the container, you bypass the need for SSH agent forwarding. The container uses the key directly for SSH operations.
That method works but has security implications, as it involves placing a sensitive SSH private key inside the container.
Storing SSH private keys directly in Docker images or containers is generally not recommended due to security concerns. If the image is ever pushed to a registry or shared, the key could be exposed.

Comment: My comment was too long, so I added it as another answer

Comment: On the host machine running `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` returns `/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh`. `ssh-add -l` works fine and returns a list of keys.

In order to check what's going on in the container I commented out the step with the `git pull` requests and then I let it build. After that I ran `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` which returns `/ssh-agent`.  `ssh-add -l` however returns `Error connecting to agent: Connection refused`

How to figure out who is the user when running the Git commands. Running `whoami` returns `root`

Comment: Running the `ssh -Tvvv git@<git-server>` on the container returns `ssh_get_authentication_socket: Connection refused`

Comment: @Xequtor ". Running whoami returns root" Then... root must be running the Git command. The error `Error connecting to agent: Connection refused when running ssh-add -l` in the container suggests that the SSH agent socket is not correctly forwarded. Run ls -l /ssh-agent in the container to check if the socket file is present and if its paths match. Instead of setting `ENV SSH_AUTH_SOCK /ssh-agent` in the Dockerfile, try dynamically setting it in the `docker-compose.yml`:
```yaml
environment:
  - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent
```

Comment: Running `ls -l /ssh-agent` in the container return `total 0`

I have SSH_AUTH_SOCK both in the Dockerfile and in the docker-compose.yml
```
environment:
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent

    volumes:
      - ../..:/workspaces:cached
      - ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}:/ssh-agent # Forward local machine SSH key to docker
```

Comment: @Xequtor The output `total 0` from the command `ls -l /ssh-agent` inside the Docker container suggests that the SSH agent socket is not being correctly mounted from the host. When the socket is correctly mounted, you should see a single entry representing the socket file, not `total 0`, which indicates an empty directory. On your host, run `ls -l $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to verify that the socket file exists and is accessible. 

Docker Compose should substitute the `${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}` variable with its value from the host environment. If not, it might be worth trying to hardcode the path as a test.

Comment: @Xequtor And remove the `ENV SSH_AUTH_SOCK /ssh-agent` line from your Dockerfile, as the `docker-compose.yml` should handle this.

Comment: `ls -l $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` returns `srwxrwxr-x 1 myuser myuser 02 January 17:42 /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh`. Looking in the Remote Explorer tab of the VSCode I see a `Bind Mount` with `Source` being that file and `Destination` being `/ssh-agent`

I used both `${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}` and its host value in the docker compose file and in both cases I am getting the same Mount

Comment: @Xequtor So the SSH agent socket from your host (`/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh`) is indeed being bound to `/ssh-agent` in your Docker container. This is a good sign: it indicates that the volume mount in your `docker-compose.yml` is working correctly. However, the fact that you are still experiencing issues suggests that there might be a problem with how the SSH agent socket is being accessed or used within the container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256454/discussion-between-vonc-and-xequtor).

Answer (score 0):

@VonC

Hey, thanks for your answer. I wanted to comment on it, but my comment will be too long so I am posting it as another answer.

I tried what you suggested but I am still getting the same unauthenticated errors. I added `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -vvv"` before the `git clone` command in order to debug. Below is the whole debug log. The only line that worries me is:

```
pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
```

Could it be somehow related to the host machine config? The ssh agent should be working on it, I ran `ssh-add -l` and it lists correctly all the keys.
Or do I need to install something additional on the devcontainer?

Here is the full log:

```
0.389 Cloning ssh://myuser@192.168.1.110:/home/myuser/repos/WebUtilities.git into WebUtilities...
0.390 Cloning into 'WebUtilities'...
0.397 OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022

0.397 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

0.397 debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files

0.397 debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *

0.397 debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.1.110 is address

0.397 debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/root/.ssh/known_hosts'

0.397 debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/root/.ssh/known_hosts2'

0.397 debug2: ssh_connect_direct

0.397 debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.110 [192.168.1.110] port 22.

0.402 debug1: Connection established.

0.402 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1

0.402 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1

0.402 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1

0.402 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1

0.402 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1

0.402 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1

0.402 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1

0.402 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1

0.402 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1

0.402 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1

0.402 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1

0.402 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1

0.403 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1

0.403 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1

0.403 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1

0.436 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u1

0.436 debug1: match: OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000

0.436 debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
[2023-12-31T10:19:01.290Z] 0.436 debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.110:22 as 'myuser'

0.436 debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"

0.436 debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1

0.436 debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.1.110

0.436 debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim

0.436 debug3: send packet: type 20

0.436 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent

0.441 debug3: receive packet: type 20

0.441 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received

0.441 debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal

0.441 debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c

0.441 debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa

0.441 debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com

0.441 debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com

0.441 debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1

0.441 debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1

0.441 debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib

0.441 debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib

0.441 debug2: languages ctos: 

0.441 debug2: languages stoc: 

0.441 debug2: first_kex_follows 0 

0.441 debug2: reserved 0 

0.441 debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal

0.441 debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256

0.441 debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519

0.441 debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com

0.441 debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com

0.441 debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1

0.441 debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1

0.441 debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com

0.441 debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com

0.441 debug2: languages ctos: 

0.441 debug2: languages stoc: 

0.441 debug2: first_kex_follows 0 

0.441 debug2: reserved 0 

0.441 debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
[2023-12-31T10:19:01.290Z] 
0.441 debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256

0.442 debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none

0.442 debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none

0.447 debug3: send packet: type 30

0.447 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY

0.517 debug3: receive packet: type 31

0.517 debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:+vI9cGum1pfe6FQYirpYXfjfnA65iZcyS9yI+O+Qrw4

0.517 debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"

0.517 debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1

0.517 debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.1.110

0.517 debug1: Host '192.168.1.110' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.

0.517 debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1

0.521 debug3: send packet: type 21

0.521 debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1

0.521 debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks

0.521 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent

0.521 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS

0.521 debug3: receive packet: type 21

0.521 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received

0.521 debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0

0.521 debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks

0.521 debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory

0.521 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa 

0.521 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa 

0.521 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa 

0.521 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 

0.521 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 

0.521 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 

0.521 debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss 

0.521 debug2: pubkey_prepare: done

0.521 debug3: send packet: type 5

0.521 debug3: receive packet: type 7

0.521 debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received

0.521 debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-dss,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>

0.521 debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com (unrecognised)

0.530 debug3: receive packet: type 6

0.530 debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth

0.530 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

0.530 debug3: send packet: type 50

0.541 debug3: receive packet: type 51

0.541 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password

0.541 debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password

0.541 debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password

0.541 debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey

0.541 debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password

0.541 debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
[2023-12-31T10:19:01.291Z] 
0.541 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey

0.541 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa

0.541 debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory

0.541 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa

0.541 debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory

0.541 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa

0.541 debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory

0.541 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk

0.541 debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory

0.541 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519

0.541 debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory

0.541 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk

0.541 debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory

0.541 debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss

0.541 debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory

0.541 debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method

0.541 debug3: authmethod_lookup password

0.541 debug3: remaining preferred: ,password

0.541 debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password

0.541 debug1: Next authentication method: password

0.541 debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address

0.541 debug3: send packet: type 50

0.541 debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply

0.552 debug3: receive packet: type 51

0.552 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password

0.552 Permission denied, please try again.

0.552 debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address

0.552 debug3: send packet: type 50

0.552 debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply

0.562 debug3: receive packet: type 51

0.562 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password

0.562 Permission denied, please try again.

0.562 debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address

0.562 debug3: send packet: type 50

0.562 debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply

0.573 debug3: receive packet: type 51

0.573 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
[2023-12-31T10:19:01.291Z] 
0.573 debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method

0.573 debug1: No more authentication methods to try.

0.573 myuser@192.168.1.110: Permission denied (publickey,password).

0.575 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
0.575 
0.575 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
0.575 and the repository exists.
```